# How to change default time value in owlDateTime?

Tags: angular, owl-date-time

**Introduction**
So I'm using owlDateTime in Angular 9 to let user select time range: from that date and time to that date and time. I'm using regular range mode, reactive form:

```
<input matInput formControlName="dateTimeRangeControl"
                 [owlDateTime]="dt"
                 [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt"
                 [selectMode]="'range'"
                 [max]="validCurrentDate">
```

**The problem**
When user selects two dates in calendar, corresponding times set to current time. So range ends looking something like this: ["2020-08-10T10:00", "2020-08-11T10:00"]. Same time in both fields.
How can I change this default time value? So it is set not to current time, but, for example, to the current time + 2 hours?

**TS**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
     ...
     dateTimeRangeControl: [[]],
    });
  }

submit(): void {
  this.backEndService.post(this.form.value);
}
```

Comment: Please also share your component.ts...

Comment: Well, i use reactive form so nothing special there. I'll add it to main answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set your hours using, `setHours()` and `getHours()` methods.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  myDate = new Date();

  constructor(){
    this.myDate.setHours(this.myDate.getHours() + 2);
  }
}
```

---

According to your update, I understand that date picker setting values by itself. This configuration should help,

**component.html**

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Date Time Range:</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="dateRange " [selectMode]="'range'"
           [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dtPicker1" [owlDateTime]="dtPicker1">
    <owl-date-time #dtPicker1></owl-date-time>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  dateRange = [];

  constructor(){
    const date = new Date();
    this.dateRange = [date, new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())];
  }
}
```

My referance is here, search in this page with keyword [Use with @angular/forms](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/)

Comment: I'm not sure i'm follow. When I click on date in calendar time is set to current time, I need it to be set to another value automatically, in the picker itself

Comment: @Kngh2 I've updated my answer. Please check this out.