# Google flights calendar like date time picker in Angular (OwlDatetime)

Tags: angular, calendar, datetimepicker, owl-date-time

I am using [Owl Date Time Picker](https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker) in my angular application. I am using range picker to select fromRange and toRange. It is displaying date time range picker like displayed below.

[image]

But I would like to show two months in the range picker like in Google flights calendar as shown in the below image. Is it possible to do the same with Owl Date Time Picker? Or is there any other library in angular to achieve the Google calendar date picker like calendar? Please advise me on this.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353013/how-to-change-default-time-value-in-owldatetime/63353204#63353204

Comment: thanks @shadowman_93 for sharing the reference. But I don't think that would solve my problem.